# Do I need to sign child processes?

Tags: .net, digital-signature, multiprocess, signtool

We are altering the structure of our Windows c#.net 4 application to being multiprocess. The UI is in the main exe, and that spawns child exe processes to do tasks.

We use a digital signature (ie. with Signtool.exe) to sign the UI exe. For windows security, do I need to also sign the child exe's?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should sign all executable.